# while loop in if statement in java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

while loop is not working in the if statement, why its not working... and how can while loop can work in if curly braces.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 30;

    if (x < 20) {
        System.out.print("This is if statement");         
        int a = 10;
        while(a < 20) {
            System.out.print("value of x : " + a );
            a++;
            System.out.print("\n");
        } 
    } else {
        System.out.print("This is else statement");
    }        
}
```

Comment: Because 30 isn't less than 20.

Comment: thanks stupidity of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared x as 30, the if loop executes `if(x<20)` which is always false, so its performing the `else` statement immediately without going thru the if statement.
You either have to declare `x` for something less than 20 or change the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement doesn't meet the condition. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int x = 10;

    if( x < 20 ) {
    System.out.print("This is if statement");         
      int a = 10;
    while( a < 20 ) {
     System.out.print("value of x : " + a );
     a++;
     System.out.print("\n");
  }


  }else {
     System.out.print("This is else statement");
  }

}
```

And output:

```
This is if statementvalue of x : 10
value of x : 11
value of x : 12
value of x : 13
value of x : 14
value of x : 15
value of x : 16
value of x : 17
value of x : 18
value of x : 19
```

Answer (score 0):

you assigned the value for x is 30 , but in your condition you are checking x is less than 20 , hence it the condition will fail and it wont execute...